# Dragged button jumps back to original position on uicollectionview scroll

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a draggable button on the screen but when I drag the button to a new position and when I scroll UICollectionView button takes its original position.

```
var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedView(_:))) 
    self.panGesture.delegate = self
    self.rightMenuColllapsedBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.rightMenuColllapsedBtn.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

@objc func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(rightMenuColllapsedBtn)
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    self.rightMenuColllapsedBtn.center = CGPoint(x: rightMenuColllapsedBtn.center.x + translation.x, y: rightMenuColllapsedBtn.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

**What I want is dragged button should remain in its dragged position even after scroll and even if view is presented and comes back to the original view.**

Comment: Have you given `rightMenuColllapsedBtn` constraints? If so, you're mixing explicit frame changes (setting its `.center` property) with auto-layout ... and auto-layout will revert to the constraints when it updates the views. You'll need to update the constraints / constants instead of setting `.center`.

Comment: yes I have set draggable view constraints with respect to another because I want a draggable view there when first shown on screen.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, if you are using constraints to position your "draggable view" then you also need to use constraints when dragging it.

Here's a quick example:

```
class DragUpdateVC: UIViewController {
    
    let rightMenuColllapsedBtn: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Collapse", for: [])
        b.setTitleColor(.white, for: [])
        b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        b.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return b
    }()
    
    var dvTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var dvLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let positionView = UIView()
        positionView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        rightMenuColllapsedBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        positionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(rightMenuColllapsedBtn)
        view.addSubview(positionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            positionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            positionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            positionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            positionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            
        ])
        
        // Top and Leading constraints for dragView
        //  that we'll update when dragged
        
        dvTop = rightMenuColllapsedBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: positionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0)
        dvLeading = rightMenuColllapsedBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: positionView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        
        dvTop.isActive = true
        dvLeading.isActive = true
        
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedView(_:)))
        rightMenuColllapsedBtn.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    }
    
    @objc func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(rightMenuColllapsedBtn)
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        
        // update Top and Leading constraint constants
        dvTop.constant += translation.y
        dvLeading.constant += translation.x
        
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
    
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

The Red view would be, perhaps, your collection view frame.

The Blue "Collapse" button starts out constrained Top to Red view Bottom (plus 20-points) and Leading to Red view Leading.

As we drag the button with the Pan gesture, we update the `.constant` values for those two constraints. Now, when we're finished dragging, the button will remain where we dropped it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the button position is maintained but it moves farther than the mouse pointer.

Comment: @NickCoder - *"it moves farther than the mouse pointer"* ... don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Actually, it means when I move my pointer view moves faster than it actually should.

Comment: Although I have found a solution without constraints I just create a button and added it as a subview and then updates the frame as it dragged, By this, I resolved both all problems 1. I add a button at initial point where I wanted 2. it doesn't lose its position in both cases a) switching views b) on collection view scroll
But your code was good as well but it had a bug